# What is the meaning of '==' in C?

Tags: c, syntax

What is the meaning of `==` and how does it differ from `=`?

How do I know which one to use?

Comment: Comments deleted because they distracted attention from the answer.  SO has a pretty clear policy of `No question is too trivial or too "newbie".` stated in the FAQ (http://stackoverflow.com/faq).  If you want to discuss that policy, please take it up on http://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`==` is a test for equality. `=` is an assignment.

Any good C book should cover this (fairly early on in the book I would imagine).

For example:

```
int i = 3;                       // sets i to 3.
if (i == 3) printf("i is 3\n");  // prints it.
```

Just watch out for the heinous:

```
if (i = 4) { }
```

which is valid C and frequently catches people out. This actually *assigns* 4 to the variable `i` and uses that as the truth value in the `if` statement. This leads a lot of people to use the uglier but safer:

```
if (4 == i) {}
```

which, if you accidentally use `=` instead of `==`, is a compile-time error rather than something that will bite you on the backside while your program is running :-)

The logical-or operator is two vertical bar characters, one after the other, *not* a single character. Here it is lined up with a logical-and, and a variable called `b4`:

```
||
&&
b4
```

No magic there.

Comment: http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/operator_precedence, http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/. Check through these websites they were a real help when I was learning C++.

Answer (score 11):

`a == b` is a **test** if *a* and *b* are equal.

`a = b` is called an **assignment**, which means to set the variable *a* to having the same value as *b*.

(You type `|` with Shift-`\` in the US keyboard layout.)

Answer (score 5):

== tests equality
= assigns a value

neither are related to ||

Answer (score 3):

I might add that in Finnish and Swedish keyboards.  Pipe symbol; |; of OR is AltGr (the right alt) and < key. IF you are using Mac on the other hand it is Alt-7 key.

Gave me a lot of sweat when I first started typing on these keyboards.

Answer (score 2):

Now that you know the difference between '==' and '=", let me put you some words of caution. Although '==' is used as a standard test of equality between comparable variables and '=' used as an internally type-casted assignment, the following programming error is quiet common.

In the below example and similar codes, '=' is know as "**Always true**" conditional operator.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i = 10, j = 20;
    if ( i = j )
        printf("Equal\n");
    else
        printf("NOT Equal\n");
    return 0;
}
```

So, the word of caution is "Never use '`=`' in `if` statements, unless you have something evil in your mind."

Comment: What? There's nothing quite so elegant as: if (fh = fopen("file.txt","r") { process_file(fh); close (fh); } // :-)

Comment: I would also call it the "always true and bugger up i as a bonus" conditional operator. But good advice so +1.

Comment: @paxdiablo: you are right... but i intended my word of caution for beginner's only. However, in goofy codes if i want a duplicate file descriptor as 'fh' this would lead to blunders: if (fd = fh = fopen("file.txt", "r") {//some code};